# How to popup dropdownlistbox on selectedindex changed event of another dropdownlistbox in same view using mvc4 asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How to display dropdownlist data on selectedindex changed event of another dropdownlistbox in same view using mvc4 asp.net

Answer (score 0):

you will need to do an ajax callback to your controller

```
$('.drop1').change(function(){
    //Clear dropdown
    $('.drop2').html('');
    $.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: { data: $this.val() },
        success: function (result) {
            //see link for populating dropdown
        }
    });
});
```

see this link for populating a dropdown with ajax result [Populating dropdown with JSON result - Cascading DropDown using MVC3, JQuery, Ajax, JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339089/populating-dropdown-with-json-result-cascading-dropdown-using-mvc3-jquery-aj)
Hopefully this helps.