# Trying to filter using two dropdownlists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I'm using MVC and I am trying to filter data through two dropdownlists.

I have one working, just don't know the logic to get the second one working

here is my code:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? DepartmentID, int? JobTitleID)
    {
        DepartmentDropDownList();
        JobDropDownList();
        var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department).Include(e => e.JobTitle);

        if (DepartmentID.HasValue || JobTitleID.HasValue)
        {
            employees = employees.Where(j => j.JobTitleID == JobTitleID);
            //somehow filter departments here
        }
        return View(employees.ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<josh_MVC_Company.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p> Select by Department: @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", "Departments")  </p>

    <p> Select by Job Title: @Html.DropDownList("JobTitleID","Job Titles")  </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by " trying to filter data through two dropdownlists"? Are trying to display list of Departments and Jobs in the dropdown list?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691882/how-to-popup-dropdownlistbox-on-selectedindex-changed-event-of-another-dropdownl/19104800#19104800

Comment: I need to filter data through two dropdownlists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter by both fields before materializing the LINQ query (`ToList()`).

```
if (JobTitleID.HasValue)
    {
        employees = employees.Where(j => j.JobTitleID == JobTitleID.Value);
    }

if (DepartmentID.HasValue)
    {
        employees = employees.Where(j => j.DepartmentID == DepartmentID.Value);
    }
return View(employees.ToList());
```

In this way, if none of the values is present, it won't be filtered at all.

(As you can see you can chain as many `Where(Expression<Func<T,bool>>)` as you want)

Comment: can't believe it was that easy. I was over thinking it